# Is it possible to create multiple versions of the same table, and if so, how?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, version

I'm currently in the process of creating a website/system and was wondering how I can create multiple versions of a table to then be used by many users. The reason for this is primarily due to the amount of information that is needed my each user. Another reason for doing so is a result of each information have been laid out to display the product code and other key information.

This is due to a main table setting a list of data for example prices of a product. To which the user then can set and store data in their own table to be used at a later date and referenced accordingly.  Rather than creating multiple columns in the thousands I feel it would be better to simply create different versions of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple table, why don't you not create seperate Views in Database based on your User and display that information in table.

Answer (score 0):

Altought, its recommended to use the single same table, and add fields that allow to restrict some data for a particular user, there is some few cases that may be required to have several versions of the table, like the ones you mention.

I have work with a web app. that served several companies, with the same tables, fields, schemas, same web server & databased server, and yet the customers want it separated from other users.

Usually, you create several tables with the same schema, but different id. Your web app. must have a way to select which table or database you are going to use.

Be very careful with this approach, is very difficult to maintain, its better to use some programming techniques to control this scenario, like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture

That allows to have a lot of control over a database app. and allows to change a table or database with thesame schema.